# Azure VPN Gateway Client - Reported as Win32/Detplock

Tags: antivirus, azure

When following this official guide to setup an Azure VPN Gateway, the downloaded VPN client application is reported as Win32/Detplock by windows defender.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal

The guide basically generates to be downloaded exe created by Microsoft.

I'm guessing this is a false positive, has anyone seen the same thing?
And is there a way to know for certain?

Comment: I've just submitted the file to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission so I'll hopefully soon find out if it's a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

It is a false positive. Just simply ignore the message from Windows Defender and run the client tool anyway.

Comment: Correct, I had the same response from windows defender. Must admit didn't get around to answering my own question.